# Using texdraw package

Tags: draw

I am trying to use the package *texdraw* in *LaTeX* to produce the image, but unfortunately *TeXShop* (version 4.44 on MacOS 10.15) does not compile normally, i.e. it stops in *Console* where I have the line with *\end{texdraw}* while previously showing the error *Unknown graphics extension .ps1*.

Here is the code itself:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}      
\usepackage{geometry}                       
\geometry{letterpaper}                          
\usepackage{graphicx}                   
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{texdraw}


\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}
\date{} 


\input txdtools
\let\et=\etexdraw
\def\etexdraw{\drawbb\et}                   

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{texdraw}
       \drawdim cm  \relunitscale 0.7 \arrowheadtype t:V
       \linewd 0.05 \lpatt (0.1 0.4)
       \move (-4 0) \avec (9 0) \move (0 -4) \avec (0 9)
       \linewd 0.1  \lpatt (1 0)


       \setgray 0.6


       \relunitscale 12
       \move (0 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.016
       \move (0 0) \rlvec (0 0.25)
       \move (0 0) \rlvec (0.25 0)
       \move (0 0) \rlvec (-0.25 -0.25)
       \move (0 0) \fcir f:0.8 r:0.008

\end{texdraw}


\end{document}
```

Is there any solution to such issue?

Comment: Nowadays texdraw is probably not worth using. Consider using tikz instead, wastly more powerful

Comment: @daleif, yes, here you're right, but the problem is that I'm using output for drawing from _Singular_ (the Computational Algebra tool) which produces the source code for _texdraw_. And I guess, there is no simple translation between these two libraries .

Comment: Then ask the developer of that tool to grow up and output in something more modern that works out of the box with all latex engines. Have you tried using the larex+dvips+ps2pdf route? It is probably not in your texshop so you have to do it by and in a terminal. Some of our old time users were using texdraw (because their docs preceeded tikz) but that was before pdflatex was the default engine.

Comment: This code is only compiled with the latex command and not pdflatex. You must change the TeXShop compilation mode so that it uses latex and not pdflatex. It should compile without error.

Comment: @gigiair, I changed the typesetting mode (on the top bar) to _TeX and DVI_, since there is no more possible option to change it, it compiles now, but there is no drawing in the produced pfd... While the document is ok.